# How to create stored procedures in DreamFactory API

Tags: mysql, api, rest, restful-url

I have added MySQL tables in the DreamFactory schema (Local Database) and trying to add a stored procedure. I see URLs for listing the existing stored procedures and calling them, but how to create them or add them into Local Database of DreamFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DreamFactory's REST API currently does not allow manipulation of stored procedures (CRUD operations), only calling them. This is partially due to the complexity across the various database platforms and partially due to security.

We will consider this as a feature request for future versions.